# Call to a member function where() an integer in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I get this error when running this code

```
public function update(StoreAccountsRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        $user->Accounts()->update($request->except('_method', '_token'))->where('accounts.user_id', '$user');
        return redirect()->route('accounts.index')->with(['message' => 'Accounts updated successfully']);
    }
```

please I need help understanding how to update a single user account in the accounts Table

Comment: Query Builder `update` returns an integer of the number of affected rows, put the `where` before the `update`  ... and i would imagine you don't have a `user_id` with value `'$user'` ... the relationship is already checking the needed foreign keys

Comment: Your query is backwards, but that `where()` clause is actually unnecessary. `$user->accounts()`, if defined properly, will already have that `where()` clause (and a correct version of it, `'$user'` won't work there) applied. Just remove it.

Comment: also if you want to update a single account, then you would need to have something to identify the specific one you want to update since it seems you have many, by the naming of the relationship

Answer (score 1):

Code must e like this

```
$user->Accounts()->update($request->except('_method', '_token'));
```